# How can I prevent uploading image everytime I edit my post in admin page?

Tags: php, database, vs-web-site-project

I created the backend of my website using PHP. Everytime I try to edit my post, I have to upload the image again. Is there a way to fetch the initial image from the storage when I try to edit my post? The code I used for updating my post is:

```
if (isset($_POST['update-post'])) {
    adminOnly();
    $errors = validatePost($_POST);

    if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $image_name = date("Ymd") . '_' . $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $destination = ROOT_PATH . "/assets/images/" . $image_name;
        $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);

        if ($result) {
            $_POST['image'] = $image_name;
        }
        else {
            array_push($errors, "Failed to upload image");
        }
    }
    else {
        array_push($errors, "Upload Image First.");
    }
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_POST['update-post'], $_POST['id']);
        $_POST['user_id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
        $_POST['published'] = isset($_POST['published']) ? 1 : 0;
        $intro = $_POST['intro'];
        $_POST['body'] = htmlentities($_POST['body']);

        $post_id = update($table, $id, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Post updated successfully.';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ' . BASE_URL . '/admin/posts/indexpost.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = isset($_POST['body']) ? $_POST['body'] : '';
        $intro = $post['intro'];
        $topic_id = $_POST['topic_id'];
        $published = isset($_POST['published']) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is you are updating the image field also while updating the row in a table so you should first remove the
else {
        array_push($errors, "Upload Image First.");
    }

Answer (score 0):

one of the common ways to avoid editing the old image is
-put in your edit form a hidden input tag and set it's value to old image name.

```
<input type="hidden" name="old_image" value="<your old image name>">
```

-then send it with the form.

- receive it in the $_POST parameters and put in in your database in case of not sending a new image

```html
if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) { 
///your upload process goes here  
} else 
{ 
$_POST['image'] = $_POST['old_image']; 
}
```